# How to align div in relation to each other?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was trying to align my elements in a certain using CSS, however, I was unable to do so.

I want part of my text to be aligned to the left, with the other part being aligned to the right at the same horizontal level.

Here is what my code looks like:
https://codesandbox.io/s/still-thunder-3yukzd?file=/src/App.js

However, as you can see there, everything is aligned to the right. What I want is for everything within the `p` tag to be aligned to the right, somewhat like this:
[image]

(The text isn't the same between both cases, however, the text is not what matters).

How would I do this using CSS and react?

Comment: your sandbox is the template demo

Comment: @dippas oops I'm sorry, I think I have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-mayer-lzwx88?file=/src/styles.css)

[image]

It will only look like this if the internal browser's width is greater than 600px. Otherwise, it will become a column.

[image]

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.App > :first-child,
.App > :last-child {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.App > :last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .App {
    justify-content: start;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .App > :first-child,
  .App > :last-child {
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but my codesandbox.io wasn't working, now it should work. When I try to do what you mentioned, I get this: https://imgur.com/a/I0gJFwf (I hope I didn't screw that over)

Comment: @saurav-chittal I've updated the post. Please check out the demo.